# Upgrade from grails 3.2 to grails 3.3, GrailsDomainClass Api Deprecated

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-3.3

I have made the following replacements to upgrade my applications and plugins to grails 3.3. (the variable name change is due to improve clarity of the replacements.)

Grails 3.2:

```
Class<?> clazz = grailsDomainClass.clazz
...

def grailsDomainClass = new DefaultGrailsDomainClass(clazz)
...

GrailsDomainClassProperty[] properties = grailsDomainClass.properties
...

def propertyName = grailsDomainClass.propertyName
...

def referenceType = grailsDomainClassProperty.referencedPropertyType
...
```

Grails 3.3:

```
Class<?> clazz = persistentEntity.javaClass
...

def persistentEntity = grailsApplication.mappingContext.getPersistentEntity(DomainClass.class.name)
...

PersistentProperty[] properties = persistentEntity.persistentProperties
...

def propertyName = persistentEntity.decapitalizedName
...

def referenceType = persistentProperty.type
```

The other changes are at [Grails 3.3 man](http://docs.grails.org/3.3.0/guide/upgrading.html).

Witch is not clear is:

1. What is the replacement for:

   ```
   grailsDomainClass.getPropertyValue(propertyName)
   ```
2. Where do I put the code which is in `doWithSpring` on my plugins?

The man page says:

> The solution is to move any logic that executes before the context is available to somewhere else that executes after the context is available.

Somewhere else were? Is there a `doWithContext` closure? It can be used to inject bean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use the `ClassPropertyFetcher.getPropertyValue` method
2. `doWithApplicationContext` is a method available to override for plugins where you can put your logic.

Comment: in grails datastore 6.0.9 `org.grails.datastore.mapping.reflect.ClassPropertyFetcher` could return non static property value. But in 6.1.6 only static property value can be extracted. What changed?